# Unable to Insert Variable in JSON string in Python

Tags: python, json

I want to replace some of the text in JSON string with a variable.

```
data = '[ { "exchange": "NSE", "tradingsymbol": "INFY", "transaction_type": "BUY", "variety": "regular", "product": "CNC", "order_type": "MARKET", "quantity": 1, "price": 0, "trigger_price": 0 } ]'
```

I changed **"INFY"** to a variable **symbol** but then I am getting an invalid JSON error when I send do requests.post()

```
symbol = "INFY"

data = '[ { "exchange": "NSE", "tradingsymbol": symbol, "transaction_type": "BUY", "variety": "regular", "product": "CNC", "order_type": "MARKET", "quantity": 1, "price": 0, "trigger_price": 0 } ]'
```

I tried looking at similar topics on stackoverflow but was unable to implement it in my code.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Updated**

```
requests.post('https://api.kite.trade/margins/orders', headers=headers, data=data)

print(requests.text)

'{"status":"error","message":"invalid json","data":{},"error_type":"InputException"}'
```

With "INFY" instead of the variable, result of print(response.text) is:

```
{"status":"success","data":[{"type":"equity","tradingsymbol":"INFY","exchange":"NSE","span":0,"exposure":0,"option_premium":0,"additional":0,"bo":0,"cash":0,"var":122.96690999999998,"pnl":{"realised":0,"unrealised":0},"total":122.96690999999998}]}
```

**Solution**

@barny's solution worked:

Updating here for closing the topic.

```
data  = '[ { "exchange": "NSE", "tradingsymbol": "INFY", "transaction_type": "BUY", "variety": "regular", "product": "MIS", "order_type": "LIMIT", "quantity": 1, "price": 100, "trigger_price": 0 } ]'
    
data1 = json.loads(data) 
data1[0]['tradingsymbol']= tradingsymbol
    
jsontext = json.dumps(data1)

response = requests.post('https://api.kite.trade/margins/orders', headers=headers, data=jsontext)
```

Comment: What is the request.post() code?

Comment: *"but was unable to implement it in my code"* - show your code.

Comment: 1) You have quotes around “INFY” - did you also put quotes around symbol? And 2) Is the JSON valid before you repace the string? If so, the simplest way to do this is to use json.loads to convert to a Python dictionary and make the change there is very simple. `data1=json.loads(data)` `data1[0][‘tradingsymbol’]=‘symbol’` `jsontext = json.dumps(data`)`

Comment: @Tomalak have updated my code in the question section

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  use json.loads to convert to a Python dictionary and make the change there, like this:

```
import json

data  = '[ { "exchange": "NSE", "tradingsymbol": "INFY", "transaction_type": "BUY", "variety": "regular", "product": "MIS", "order_type": "LIMIT", "quantity": 1, "price": 100, "trigger_price": 0 } ]'

data1=json.loads(data)
data1[0]['tradingsymbol']='symbol'
jsontext = json.dumps(data)
```